# MongoDb date query issue

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a leave transaction table like below

```
{
    "leaveDuration": 1,
    "leaveDurationDetail": 1,
    "fromDate": {
        "$date": "2021-11-25T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "toDate": {
        "$date": "2021-11-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "leaveStatus": 1,
    "availableBalance": 9,
    "reason": "World Tour",
    "userId": {
        "$oid": "618cc2e592dffdd7e1257cb4"
    },
    "days": -1,
    "leaveType": {
        "$oid": "618b67968569132637760cb7"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-11-12T09:13:07.239Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-11-12T09:13:07.239Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

You can see the above leave entry with 25th(fromDate) to 27th(toDate).

The query below is to check if the entered dates are already applied as leave or not.

```
[
    {
        '$match': {
            '$or': [
                {
                    '$and': [
                        {
                            'fromDate': {
                                '$lte': new Date('Tue, 25 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT')
                            }
                        }, {
                            'toDate': {
                                '$gte': new Date('Tue, 25 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT')
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    '$and': [
                        {
                            'fromDate': {
                                '$lte': new Date('Sun, 28 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT')
                            }
                        }, {
                            'toDate': {
                                '$gte': new Date('Sun, 28 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT')
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

You see the above query will return the data means the leave is already applied.

But this query is **not working for 24 to 28**.

So I understand the problem here that 24 is smaller than 25 and 28 is larger than 27 so it won't return any data.

But what query can we make to get the dates in between ?

If leave is applied from 25 to 27. How can we create a query in which if 24 to 28 is entered that it will return that your leave of 25 to 27 is already applied so 24 to 28 is not allowed as 25 to 27 comes in between 24 to 28.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your query wont work if both Entered dates are same. So you might need 2 queries on based on condition

```
if(enteredFromDate == enteredToDate){

  fromDate: { $lte: yourEnteredfromDate },
  toDate: { $gte: yourEnteredfromDate }  

} else {
        $or: [{
            $and: [{
                fromDate: {
                    $gte: yourEnteredfromDate
                }
            }, {
                toDate: {
                    $gte: yourEnteredfromDate
                }
            }, ]
        }, 
        {
            $and: [{
                fromDate: {
                    $lte: yourEnteredtoDate
                }
            }, {
                toDate: {
                    $lte: yourEnteredtoDate
                }
            }, ]
        }]
    }
}
```

This will full-fill all your dates. And provide Overlapping data.

Answer (score -1):

So all you have to do is change your logic, let's word it out first.

We want the "start" date to be greater than input `x` and we want the "end" date to be less than input `y`.

Now the query is quite simple:

```
[
    {
        '$match': {
            fromDate: {$gte: new Date('Tue, 24 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT')},
            toDate: {$lte: new Date('Sun, 28 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT')},
        }
    }
]
```

This will match any "leave" that starts after the 24, and ends prior to the 28th.

---- EDIT ----

For matching any dates you can use this:

```
[
    {
        '$match': {
            $or: [
                {
                    fromDate: {
                        $gte: new Date('Tue, 24 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT'),
                        $lte: new Date('Sun, 28 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT')
                    },
                },
                {
                    toDate: {
                        $gte: new Date('Tue, 24 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT'),
                        $lte: new Date('Sun, 28 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT')
                    },
                },
                {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            fromDate: {$lte: new Date('Tue, 24 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT')},
                        },
                        {
                            toDate: {$gte: new Date('Tue, 24 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT')},
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            fromDate: {$lte: new Date('Sun, 28 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT')},
                        },
                        {
                            toDate: {$gte: new Date('Sun, 28 Nov 2021 00:00:00 GMT')},
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: This won't work. Imagine if entered 26 to 28.  It won't return anything.

Comment: So what you're saying you want if there's ANY overlap between your input and the document you want it matched? because you specifically asked dates in between.

Comment: Yes if overlapping dates found than the query will return me that overlapping row and I will get to know that leave is already applied. Its overlapping with my entered dates.

Comment: I added it as an edit.

Comment: The edited version will also not work . Image entering both fromDate and toDate as 26

Comment: I added in the final query, you do realize you're merging two different queries into one logic like this yea?

Comment: Still it won't work for 26 as said above

Comment: You will need a condition if fromDate == toDate than a query else your usal query. In code .